# Is the complement of an hypersuface in $\mathbb{A}^n$ also an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have read the Lemma 4.2 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry. I could almost understand the isomorphism between the complement $\mathbb{A}^n-Y=\mathbb{A}^n-Z(f)$ and the hypersurface $H=Z(x_{n+1}f-1)$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$. And so this means $\mathbb{A}^n-Y$ is an affine variety.

Let $X=Z(f)$ be a hypersurface (affine variety) in $\mathbb{A}^n$ given by an irreducible polynomial $f\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, then we could conclude that $\mathbb{A}^n-X$ is also an affine variety. However, by the definition of affine variety, both $X$ and $\mathbb{A}^n-X$ are irreducible closed subsets in $\mathbb{A}^n$ with Zariski topology. Then since $X\cup (\mathbb{A}^n-X)=\mathbb{A}^n$, it contradict with $\mathbb{A}^n$ is irreducible (also the complement of a closed subset should be open).

Comment: $\mathbb{A}^n - X$ is not closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Rather, it's isomorphic to a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^{n + 1}$, as that lemma shows.

Comment: @Daniel So $\mathbb{A}^n-X$ is a quasi-affine variety but not an affine variety? Is it possible an quasi-affine variety isomorphic to an affine variety?

Comment: The correct definition of an affine variety is any variety that is isomorphic to a closed irreducible subset of affine space. I believe Hartshorne redefines an affine variety right before Lemma 4.2 for this purpose.

Comment: Looking at the book, Hartshorne doesn't really make this as clear as I thought. This sort of refinement of the definition is common after you learn about morphisms, and I think that's the intention in Hartshorne's definition of the adjective *affine*.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you so much, Daniel. It is really useful, I could understand it now.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3876126/) for some previous discussion about the redefinition of affine variety in Hartshorne.

Comment: @KReiser That is exactly what I confused! Thank you, KReiser. However, do you know what exactly the 'affine ring' of $\mathbb{A}^n-Y$ in this lemma means? It seems not like the coordinate ring of the quasi-affine variety $\mathbb{A}^n-Y$, but is equal to the coordinate ring of the isomorphic affine variety $H=Z(x_{n+1}f-1)$.

Comment: It's the ring of all regular functions on your variety. This is a piece of intrinsic data not depending on the embedding. If that link resolves your issues, I'd be happpy to mark this question as resolved by those answers.

Comment: @KReiser Oh, I get it! Many thanks to you! That link absolutely resolve all my issues.